# Javascript reserved words

Tags: javascript

I made an object which worked fine with FF but resulted in an error with IE (expected identifier, string or number)

```
var a={text:'abc',class:'def'};
```

After a litter research, I found class is a reserved word.  Quoting the word "class" fixed the problem.

```
var a={text:'abc',"class":'def'};
```

Is it recommended to always quote the object name to eliminate these errors?

Thanks

Comment: no harm in not using quotes if you know the reserved keywords. if you don't know them or you want to future-proof, be safe. another instance where this helps is when working with css props like `"border-width": value` vs `borderWidth: value`

Comment: It's recommended to avoid using reserved words as custom properties/methods :)

Comment: what bothers me is that the keywords reserved for future use are highlighted in editors, leading to annoyances (`express.static` for example).

Comment: Here I expleained why Reserved words or Keywords cannot be use and provide you a link with a list of Keywords in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922701/4066742

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not something that is generally recommended.

What IS recommended is to simply not used reserved words like this. You can quite easily change `class` to be anything else.

Comment: depends, for example, the mootools element constructor expects 'class' to set the className - no way around that other than quotes.

Comment: jQueryUI Dialog also uses the word class.

Answer (score 4):

Just have a look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

and don't use any of those words unquoted within object literals.

Comment: Should text also not be used or quoted? http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm